# primefaces 5.0 Calendar icons are not coming for button and internal calendar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, icons

I am not using `PrimeFaces` theme and don't want to use any theme. For calender the image and icons are not coming. Only blank button is coming. Please let me know how to get all the icons without using any `PrimeFaces` theme.
My `.xml` code is

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and my `.xhtml` code is

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarManagedBean.date}" showOn="button" />
```

I am not able to upload the image. But calendar is coming and button also. But calendar icon and calendar internal icons are not coming

Comment: is this happening only for calendar, or other components also ? e.g. what happens when you add `<p:command icon="ui-icon-plus">` ? do you see the icon getting rendered?

Comment: also, have you tried deleting the `context-param` xml node from web.xml

Comment: It is happening for calender only.Yes I have tried both. when I am removing the context-param it will effect other components and when I am using icon="ui-icon-plus/ui-icon-calendar" it is showing just blank button with icon.Please suggest.

Comment: Looks like a css conflict. For example, there is well-known incompatibility issue with Liferay 6.2 and Primefaces 5.0 (https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1823). Where do you deploy your servlet/portlet ? Can you give us some info on that ?

Comment: Tried with other normal JavaScript and CSS for calendar that also not loading . I tried on both using Tomcat server/WebSphere server.It's normal Dynamic web project which include JSF 2.0. We are using our foundation.CSS But I tried removing that also but effect. It's only changing when adding some Theme name.:-(